# Beautiful Soup - Print a containers text without printing the text of the child elements

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

How can I target text within a container without getting the child elements text too? For example how could I target the text `Toshiba Satellite Pro C850-1GR Satellite Pro, 1.8 GHz`
in the below HTML

**My Attempt**

```
short_description=soup.find('div',{'class':'info-item description product-short-desc c_both'}).text
print short_description
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="product-short-summary-wrap">
<b class="tip-anchor tip-anchor-wrap">Short summary description Toshiba Satellite Pro C850-1GR</b>ev
:
<br/>
<div class="tooltip-text">This short summary of the data-sheet.</div>
 Toshiba Satellite Pro C850-1GR Satellite Pro, 1.8 GHz
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select `div` element that is above and use `nextSibling`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<div id="product-short-summary-wrap">\
<b class="tip-anchor tip-anchor-wrap">Short summary description Toshiba Satellite Pro C850-1GR</b>ev\
:\
<br/>\
<div class="tooltip-text">This short summary of the data-sheet.</div>\
 Toshiba Satellite Pro C850-1GR Satellite Pro, 1.8 GHz\
</div>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

text = soup.find("div", {"class":"tooltip-text"})
print text.nextSibling.string
```

Output:

```
Toshiba Satellite Pro C850-1GR Satellite Pro, 1.8 GHz
```

---

If div has `This short summary of the data-sheet` in it, then you can try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<div id="product-short-summary-wrap">\
<b class="tip-anchor tip-anchor-wrap">Short summary description Toshiba Satellite Pro C850-1GR</b>ev\
:\
<br/>\
<div class="tooltip-text">This short summary of the data-sheet.</div>\
 Toshiba Satellite Pro C850-1GR Satellite Pro, 1.8 GHz\
</div>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

text = soup.find("div", {"class":"tooltip-text"})
if "This short summary of the data-sheet." in text.string:
        print text.nextSibling.string
```

Output:

```
Toshiba Satellite Pro C850-1GR Satellite Pro, 1.8 GHz
```

---

I think you have posted wrong HTML in the PasteBin, but I found which site you want to scrap. I'm not sure which page exactly so here is what I have found and done. If you go to this [page](http://icecat.biz/p/toshiba/pscbxe-01t01gfr/satellite-pro-notebooks-4051528036589-C8501GR-17411822.html) you can find same HTML part as in your question. My code to extract text:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://icecat.biz/p/toshiba/pscbxe-01t01gfr/satellite-pro-notebooks-4051528036589-C8501GR-17411822.html"
html = urllib2.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

texts = soup.findAll("div", {"class":"tooltip-text"})
for text in texts:
    if text.string:
        if "This short summary of the" in text.string:
            print text.nextSibling.string.strip()
```

Output:

```
Toshiba C850-1GR Satellite Pro, 1.8 GHz, Intel Celeron, 1000M, 4 GB, DDR3-SDRAM, 1600 MHz
```

Same thing for diffrent [URL](http://icecat.biz/p/intel/h2312wpfjr/server-barebones-0675900020627-H2312WPFJR-14093358.html), output:

```
Intel H2312WPFJR, Socket R (2011), Intel, Xeon, 2048 GB, DDR3-SDRAM, 2048 GB
```

If you need you can split string after you find it

Comment: I have multiple classes of tooltip-text in my document though :( so it returns the wrong area for me

Comment: Does it always have `This short summary of the data-sheet`, or maybe it's always Toshiba? Or maybe there is just one `product-short-summary-wrap` id element? Or do you see any other pattern?

Comment: It has short summary description.

Comment: I updated my answer. Try this, if this still won't work, try to find another pattern

Comment: Well, then the only option for you is to post the whole HTML

Comment: The whole HTML is massive! I can e-mail it to you if you want to try have a crack at it?

Comment: I can't find div element in code that you posted in pastebin. Are you sure that correct page?

Comment: Sorry my parser gave me wrong html page I have updated it now- http://pastebin.com/2iNfYaAC