# Find Text With No Tag in ContentPane with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

My question is similar to these: [Get HTML Text that has no tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919291/get-html-text-that-has-no-tag),
[Beautiful Soup - Print a containers text without printing the text of the child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474484/beautiful-soup-print-a-containers-text-without-printing-the-text-of-the-child)

How can I get this text from the ContentPane: `Updated September 11, 2018 (57) Cases + (1) traffic w/contributing heroin`?

**HTML:**

```
<!--Container Content-->
<div class="contentmain">
    <div id="dnn_ctr3799_ContentPane" class="contentpane">
        <!--Start_Module_3799-->
        Updated September 11, 2018 (57) Cases + (1) traffic w/contributing heroin
```

**Attempt 1** `soup.find`:

I'm able to print the whole ContentPane, including the above text, using `soup.find`, but I don't want it all:

```
name_box = soup.find(id= 'dnn_ctr3799_ContentPane')
name = name_box.text.strip()
print name
```

**Attempt 2** `nextSibling`:

I tried `nextSibling` but I get no result.

```
texts = soup.findAll("div", {"id":"dnn_ctr3799_ContentPane"})
for text in texts:
    if text.string:
        if "dnn_ctr3799_ContentPane" in text.string:
            print text.nextSibling.string.strip()
```

Link to webpage: [2018 Heroin/Fentanyl Overdose Deaths](https://www.willcountyillinois.com/County-Offices/Judicial-Services/Coroner/2018-Overdose-Statistics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's a **Container** I'm dealing with. And the string I want is a `sibling` of the string `<!--Start_Module_3799-->` under the parent `<div id="dnn_ctr3799_ContentPane" class="contentpane">`

**Answer:**

```
texts = soup.find('div', id='dnn_ctr3799_ContentPane')
name = texts.find_next(string=True)
print od.nextSibling.string
```